# Mock an object with a constructor mockito

Tags: java, spring, web-services, junit, mockito

i have class

```
Class A {
ServiceClass serviceClass;
public A(ServiceClass  obj){
serviceClass = obj;
}
public String methodA(String i){
   String j = serviceClass.someMethod(i);
return j;
}

}
```

here  i have some method in  that i m calling service class method for that i have created mock object for service class.

```
ServiceClass serviceClassMock = Mockito.mock(ServiceClass.class);
A objA = new A(serviceClassMock);
@Test
public void test(){
 when(serviceClassMock.someMethod("1")).thenReturn("1");
 String j = objA.methodA("1");// here gives me wanted be invoked but not. there where 0 interaction

verify(serviceClassMock).someMethod("1");
```

}

Comment: Can you show us the method that you're trying to test?

Comment: Is there a `verify` in your test somewhere?

Comment: @DavidWallace yes  verify(serviceClassMock).someMethod("1"); also check edited

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this.  I assume `ServiceClass` isn't `final`, and its methods aren't `final`, right?

Answer (score 1):

for example:

```
Impl a= new Impl("ei");
Impl m = Mockito.mock(Impl.class);

when(m.someCall(Matchers.any(Object.class))).thenReturn(whereverYouWanna);
```

or more specific:

```
when(m.someCall(Matchers.eq(24)).thenReturn(whereverYouWanna);
```

is very important to know that your previous simulations may limit your mocked code, I hope it helps you.

Comment: i try this but no result same error.plz check edited